# How to get Javascript working on Android 4.1

Tags: javascript, android

I have to use JavaScript within the stock browser of LG Optimus 4XD (Android version 4.1.2 / browser version 4.1.41104).

Not even this minimal HTML/JavaScript page works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>What Can JavaScript Do?</h2>

<p id="demo">JavaScript can change HTML content.</p>

<button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript!"'>Click Me!</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Do you have any ideas how to get JavaScript working on Android stock browser?

Edit:

Also this doesn't work (nothing is shown in the browser window):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        var isEngineES5Compliant = ('create' in Object && 'isArray' in Array);
        document.write(isEngineES5Compliant ? "ES5 works" : "ES5 doesn't work");
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is javascript enabled? From browser menu Settings > Advanced > Enable Javascript? (wording probably depends on language)

Comment: yes I checked that beforehand

Answer (score 1):

Don't use ES6 syntax, ES5 probably will work, but for sure execute this code:

```
var isEngineES5Compliant = ('create' in Object && 'isArray' in Array);
alert(isEngineES5Compliant ? "ES5 works" : "ES5 doesn't work");
```

You can also put old version of jQuery.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, see my edit of the original post. Also document.write does not work (double checked that javascript is enabled).

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, the problem was the Content Security Policy. The old Android stock browser ignored the 'unsafe-inline' entry:

```
Content-Security-Policy:default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'
```

Is there a special CSP Syntax for this type of browsers?